# Preterite vs Imperfect

Tags: pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto

> Su obra y su personalidad le situaron pronto a la cabeza del grupo.

Why don't you use the imperfect tense for the verb situar?

Comment: Key word here is "pronto", which implies a single action.  Take it out and both *situaron* and *situaban* work perfectly well.

Comment: @guifa pronto means soon. How does soon imply a single action?

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the "trigger" word schemes for making grammar choices. In this case, think of the promotion. It happened once. It's not an ongoing process, but a once-and-done action, or "event". That makes preterite a perfect fit.

Comment: how do you know that the action happened once?

Comment: I'm sensing it from context. Besides, "head" of a group is superlative; can't repeat it.

Comment: who would repeat it? do you mean someone else repeats it or the person i'm talking about repeats it?

Comment: @guifa why can't superlatives be repeated? What if I take over the group and kick that person out and become head of the group? Then can't I repeat the action?